# vbPixel position to real pixel position

Tags: c#, graphics, vb6, bitmap

I am importing data that was exported from a vb6 application into a new app made in c#.net.
The pixel coordinates in the data are in vbPixels. Is there a way to convert them into the real pixel coordinate? The bitmap is 800x500 and the pixels are like x=2265 y=1620.

Comment: `vbPixels` is the identifier for real pixels. If they are coming out different then there is another problem involved. if the values are actually twips (identified by `vbTwips` then the conversion factor is 15 on a normal DPI system. See `Screen.TwipsPerPixelX/Y` for the factor on yoru machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [these functions from .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a59w6f5.aspx):

ToPixelsX - Used for coordinate conversion.

ToPixelsY - Used for coordinate conversion.

And [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy2xdatz.aspx) to understand what is going on. Twips have a very special definition that is dependent on resolution.

In my previous answer I assumed that you knew that the give coordinate was the size of the image.

Comment: The pixel (2265|1620) is inside the bitmap. I need the scale factor that vb6 uses to calculate the vbPixels.

Comment: Those functions are Obsolete. But using them once it seems that the scale factor is 15.

Comment: Yes they are obsolete because Microsoft does not want to guarantee that these functions will be available for ever. They are meant for migrations. So write your code using these to migrate the data and then never use the functions in new code.

Answer (score 0):

in VB6 you can use

```
Screen.TwipsPerPixelx
```

and

```
Screen.TwipsPerPixelY
```

These are almost always 15, but the user could change some settings which might result in other values (i am not sure which settings though :))